# Can COPY FROM tolerantly consume bad CSV?

Tags: postgresql, etl, postgresql-9.1

I am trying to load text data into a postgresql database via `COPY FROM`.  Data is definitely not clean **CSV**.

The input data isn't always consistent: sometimes there are excess fields (separator is part of a field's content) or there are nulls instead of 0's in integer fields.

The result is that PostgreSQL throws an error and stops loading.

Currently I am trying to massage the data into consistency via perl.

Is there a better strategy?

Can PostgreSQL be asked to be as tolerant as **mysql** or **sqlite** in that respect?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL's `COPY FROM` isn't designed to handle bodgy data and is quite strict. There's little support for tolerance of dodgy data.

I thought there was little interest in adding any until I saw [this proposed patch](http://archives.postgresql.org/message-id/002101cd9190%24081c4140%241854c3c0%24@lab.ntt.co.jp) posted just a few days ago for possible inclusion in PostgreSQL 9.3. The patch has been resoundingly rejected, but shows that there's some interest in the idea; read the thread.

It's sometimes possible to `COPY FROM` into a staging `TEMPORARY` table that has all `text` fields with no constraints. Then you can massage the data using SQL from there. That'll only work if the SQL is at least well-formed and regular, though, and it doesn't sound like yours is.

If the data isn't clean, you need to pre-process it with a script in a suitable scripting language.

Have that script:

- Connect to PostgreSQL and `INSERT` rows;
- Connect to PostgreSQL and use the scripting language's Pg APIs to `COPY` rows in; or
- Write out clean CSV that you can `COPY FROM`

Python's `csv` module can be handy for this. You can use any language you like; perl, python, php, Java, C, whatever.

If you were enthusiastic you could write it in `PL/Perlu` or `PL/Pythonu`, inserting the data as you read it and clean it up. I wouldn't bother.